# Downloading zip files from FTP server in R: Connection refused, port 80

Tags: r, ftp, connection

I'm trying to download some zip files from a larger directory on a FTP server. Currently I have code to load the directory and search for zip files then download all files with a .zip extension.

```
url <- "ftp://ftp.zakupki.gov.ru/fcs_regions/Adygeja_Resp/protocols/"
userpw <- "free:free"
protocol <- getURL(url, userpwd=userpw, ftp.use.epsv=TRUE, dirlistonly=TRUE)
filenames <- protocol <- strsplit(protocol, "\r*\n")[[1]]
write.table(filenames, "names.txt", sep="\t")
zips <- sapply(filenames,function(x) substr(x,nchar(x)-2,nchar(x)))== "zip"
downloads <- filenames[zips]
con <-  getCurlHandle(ftp.use.epsv = TRUE, userpwd=userpw)
mapply(function(x,y) writeBin(getBinaryURL(x, curl = con, dirlistonly = FALSE), y), x = downloads, y = paste("C://temp//",downloads, sep = ""))
```

Last night I ran the code and was able to download the files with no problems, however when I tried running it again today I received the following error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Failed to connect to protocol_Adygeja_Resp_2014030100_2014040100_20140710102838_001.xml.zip port 80: Connection refused
```

I've tried turning off the internet2 setting in R, as well as changing the ftp.use.espv setting. I'm quite certain the code I have listed above ran fine the first time however and none of the setting changes I've tried have helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked for me, but you might want to give it a try with the more modern `curl` package:

```
library(curl)

# Get dir listing ---------------------------------------------------------

list_h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(list_h, userpwd=userpw, ftp_use_epsv=TRUE, dirlistonly=TRUE)
con <- curl(url, "r", handle=list_h)
protocol <- readLines(con)
close(con)

# Save off a list of the filenames ----------------------------------------

writeLines(protocol, con="names.txt")

# Filter out only .zip files ----------------------------------------------

just_zips <- grep("\\.zip$", protocol, value=TRUE)

# Download the files ------------------------------------------------------

dl_h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(dl_h, userpwd=userpw, ftp_use_epsv=TRUE)
for (i in seq_along(just_zips)) {
  curl_fetch_disk(url=sprintf("%s%s", url, just_zips[i]),
                  path=sprintf("/tmp/%s", just_zips[i]),
                  handle=dl_h)
}
```

You'll need to change `/tmp` but this worked fine on my Mac. I don't have a handy-enough Windows system to try it on there.

Comment: Thanks! That code works for me, still not sure why my original code works for you but not on my computer... Very strange.